# How to add points in QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am new to Qt. I have seen the sample codes of adding rectangle, ellipse and line in a QGraphicView. Please help to add a single point in the GraphicsView by giving the x,y coordinate?

```
QGraphicsScene scene(0,0,800,600); 
QGraphicsView view(&scene); 
scene.addText("Hello, world!"); 
QPen pen(Qt::green); 
scene.addLine(0,0,200,200,pen); 
scene.addEllipse(400,300,100,100,pen); 
view.show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add points in qgraphicsview u can use following code snippet..

```
double rad = 1;
scene->addEllipse(x-rad, y-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0, 
            QPen(), QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
```

where x and y are points where you want to add the point in qgraphicsview.